# jquery calculation need assistance.!

Tags: jquery

The problem is that when you hit the equals sign on the calculator it says 
`Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`. Can someone explain to me what im doing wrong

```
$("#Num_View").val($("#Num_View").val() = eval($("#Num_View").val()));
```

Comment: `eval()`ing user input is likely a bad idea, and I suspect is the root of your problem. The `eval()` is likely interpretting your `=` as an assignment in Javascript.

Comment: I guess you meant to type `$("#Num_View").val(eval($("#Num_View").val()))` ?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the return of the val() function (which is a string literal) equal to something else. This can't be done.

```
$("#Num_View").val() = eval($("#Num_View").val()
```

That part is throwing the error. If you want to compare those values you need to use double equals `==` OR if you want to set the value you need to pass it as a parameter to the val function like

```
$("#Num_View").val(eval($("#Num_View").val())
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a value to the result of a function that returns a string, which isn't valid.

I think what you're going for is this:

```
$("#Num_View").val($("#Num_View").val() + ' = ' + eval($("#Num_View").val()));
```

Which would convert user input of `2 + 3` to `2 + 3 = 5`.

Or better:

```
$("#Num_View").val(function(_, oldValue) {
    return oldValue + ' = ' + eval(oldValue);
});
```

However, `eval()`ing user input is definitely a bad idea.